# Como un sensor de Temperatura y Humedad DHT22 puede enviar los datos via post a un PHP incluyendo la fecha y la hora de la lectura del sensor?

Tags: arduino, yaml, esp32

Tengo un problema, no sé cómo enviar la información de un sensor de Temperatura y Humedad DHT22 vía post a un PHP y lo otro que se presenta es como incluir la fecha y la hora de la lectura del sensor.

Aquí el código que tengo:

```
esphome:
  name: esphome-web-123456
  friendly_name: Temperatura&Humedad

esp32:
  board: esp32dev
  framework:
    type: arduino

# Enable logging
logger:

# Enable Home Assistant API
api:
  encryption:
    key: "AQUI LA LLAVE"

ota:

wifi:
  ssid: !secret wifi_ssid
  password: !secret wifi_password

  # Enable fallback hotspot (captive portal) in case wifi connection fails
  ap:
    ssid: "Esphome-Web-123456"
    password: "AQUI LA CLAVE"

captive_portal:

sensor:
  - platform: dht
    pin: 15
    temperature:
      name: "Temperatura"
      id: temperatura_sensor
    humidity:
      name: "Humedad"
      id: "humedad_sensor"
    update_interval: 600s // SENSA Y ENVIA LOS DATOS CADA 10 MINUTOS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al crear el Sensor en el archivo "nombredeldispositivo.yaml" en el complemento de Home Assistant llamado "ESPHome" creas un script en la sección del sensor y en el mismo crea un apartado "lambda" (compilador en C) donde creas el valor de la fecha y hora y lo llevas a la variable "fecha_hora" para luego asignarla a la variable global definida al principio del código (id(fecha_actual) = fecha_hora;) con dichos valores para ser tomada en cuenta en el scope, es importante haber creado el componente "time" dentro del código el cual te va a configurar y dar la fecha y hora del ESP32.

Luego se realiza el "http_request.post" pasando la URL y los valores en formato JSON, es importante aclarar que toda variable que le antecede la palabra: "!secret" es porque dicha variable se encuentra en el archivo "secret.yaml".

```
esphome:
  name: esphome-web-123456
  friendly_name: Temperatura&Humedad

globals:
  - id: fecha_actual
    type: std::string
    initial_value: ""
    restore_value: false

time:
  - platform: homeassistant
    id: fecha_y_hora

esp32:
  board: esp32dev
  framework:
    type: arduino

# Enable logging
logger:

# Enable Home Assistant API
api:
  encryption:
    key: "AQUI LA LLAVE"

ota:

wifi:
  ssid: !secret wifi_ssid
  password: !secret wifi_password

  # Enable fallback hotspot (captive portal) in case wifi connection fails
  ap:
    ssid: "Esphome-Web-123456"
    password: "AQUI LA CLAVE"

captive_portal:

web_server:

http_request:
  id: http_request_data
  useragent: esphome/device
  timeout: 10s

sensor:
  - platform: dht
    pin: 15
    temperature:
      name: "Temperatura"
      id: temperatura_sensor
    humidity:
      name: "Humedad"
      id: "humedad_sensor"
      on_value:
        then:
          - script.execute: src_enviar_post
    update_interval: 600s // SENSA Y ENVIA LOS DATOS CADA 10 MINUTOS

script:
  - id: src_enviar_post
    then:
      - lambda: |-
          auto timeinC = id(fecha_y_hora).now();
          int anio = timeinC.year;
          int mes = timeinC.month;
          int dia = timeinC.day_of_month;
          int hora = timeinC.hour;
          int minutos = timeinC.minute;
          int segundos = timeinC.second;
          // Convertir las variables en una cadena de caracteres
          char fecha_hora[20];
          sprintf(fecha_hora, "%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", anio, mes, dia, hora, minutos, segundos);
          id(fecha_actual) = fecha_hora;
      - http_request.post:
          url: !secret url_PHP_POST_JSON_TempHumed
          verify_ssl: false
          json: |-
            char temperatura[10];
            dtostrf(id(temperatura_sensor).state, 5, 2, temperatura);
            char humedad[10];
            dtostrf(id(humedad_sensor).state, 5, 2, humedad);
            root["fecha"] = id(fecha_actual);
            root["dispositivo"] = "esphome_web_6522a4";
            root["temperatura"] = temperatura;
            root["humedad"] = humedad;
          on_response:
            then:
              - logger.log:
                  level: INFO
                  tag: http_post
                  format: "HTTP POST Response status: %d"
                  args: [status_code]

              - lambda: |-
                  if (status_code == 200) {
                    ESP_LOGI("http_post", "HTTP POST successful");
                  } else {
                    ESP_LOGI("http_post", "HTTP POST failed");
                  }
```